# Evaluate $\lim_{x\to\infty} (1+\frac{2}{x})^{5x}$ without L'Hopital

Tags: calculus, limits, limits-without-lhopital

I'm trying to evaluate the following limit

$$\lim_{x\to\infty} \left(1+\frac{2}{x}\right)^{5x}$$

I recognize a part of this limit because it resembles the limit for $e$ but I don't know anything other than that. I have no idea where to start. Some hints would be much appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Write $y = \frac{x}{2}$.  Then we want $\displaystyle \lim_{y\rightarrow\infty}\left(1+\frac{1}{y}\right)^{10y}$.  Since the function $g(z) = z^{10}$ is continuous, this is $$\lim_{y\rightarrow\infty}g\left(\left(1+\frac{1}{y}\right)^{y}\right) = g\left(\lim_{y\rightarrow\infty}\left(1+\frac{1}{y}\right)^{y}\right) = \left(\lim_{y\rightarrow\infty}\left(1+\frac{1}{y}\right)^y\right)^{10} = e^{10}.$$

Answer (score 4):

**Hint:** $y:=x/2$, then $5x=10y$ and we have
$$\left(1+\frac2x\right)^{5x}=\left(1+\frac1y\right)^{y\cdot 10}\,.$$

Answer (score 4):

Hint:
$$
\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}\left(1+\frac{2}{x}\right)^\frac{x}{2}=e
$$